# How to save displayed PDF in active tab (not printing)?

Tags: applescript

I have a file displayed in a browser (Vivaldi in my case, which I think is identical to Chrome) which is a direct link to a actual PDF (i.e. the URL ends with ".pdf"). How do I simply save it to disk?

I tried this:

```
tell application "Vivaldi"
    save active tab of front window in "/blah/blah/blah.pdf"
end tell
```

I get a file with a PDF extension saved in the right place, but it can't be opened. macOS says it's "corrupted". The file is also slightly larger that the one I get if I download it normally. Obviously it is not saving the PDF directly "as is", which is simply achieved using Command/Ctrl+S. I can try to simulate it with Command+S and then Command+Shift+H to change paths but it seems very inelegant.

What am I doing wrong?

I should add that I'm looking to save a PDF which is already displayed in a browser, not fetch a PDF from a URL, as this is a subscriber password-protected website.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This following AppleScript code should be able to download any PDF file from a URL (as long as you don't have to supply a username and password to access that site containing the PDF file).

The comments in the code should make it pretty easy to understand.  All you need to do is edit the `downloadsFolder` , `pdfURL` , and `pdfFileName` variables in the first three lines of the code.

That is a functioning URL with a PDF file that will be downloaded to your Downloads folder.   First run this AppleScript code "as is" in Script Editor.  Then edit the code to suit your needs

```
-- Destination Folder For The Downloaded PDF
property downloadsFolder : (path to downloads folder) as text

-- Full URL Of The PDF File To Be Downloaded
set pdfURL to "https://web.archive.org/web/20150406042817/http://files.macscripter.net/sourcebook/AS4ASb2.pdf"

-- Filename To Save The PDF As
set pdfFileName to "Applescript For Absolute Starters.pdf"

set savedFile to downloadsFolder & pdfFileName

do shell script "curl " & quoted form of pdfURL & " -o " & quoted form of POSIX path of savedFile

tell application "Finder"
    activate
    repeat until frontmost
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    reveal alias savedFile
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry but I should have mentioned that the PDF is accessed on a password-protected site. I've edited the question to reflect that.